# google app engine not running after upgrading to yosemite

Tags: python, google-app-engine, osx-yosemite

I recently upgraded my macbook to yosemite, and am having trouble starting the google app engine. When I try to run any app, I get a yellow clock, and all options are greyed out.

When I look in GAE prefs, the default python path is

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

but yosemite does not use that location

```
$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

I have tried entering that value in the GAE prefs, but I still get the same issue. I also tried installing the newest ver of python, but it installed in the same loc, with no option to install in /usr/local/bin

Do I need to do something in terms of the symlinks? Has anyone else run across this issue?

thanks, 
bp

Comment: Haven't tried Yosemite yet, but in your shoes I'd first try a ln -s from the /Library/... location into /usr/local/bin/ ... would that work?  Let us know!

Comment: @AlexMartelli; It started working. added the new python location in prefs and started a new application, and that did the trick. Still not 100% sure why it worked, though.